# Minimum Button Spacing

Tags: ios, uibutton, user-experience

Is there an Apple guideline on how much **spacing** there should be **between** 2 buttons? I just found the guideline about the minimum size of 44x44.

Sidethought: Placing buttons in IB will snap to a default minimum **spacing**, but is this a rule that should be obeyed? In some WWDC talk an apple guy once mentioned that the Apple guidelines are built into IB.

Comment: no it is not. you can use any size you want in case of buttons or any other controls.

Comment: Your app won't be rejected because a button is so small that no one can tap.

Comment: i tagged this question with user-experience for a reason...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

iOS Human Interface Guidelines reads...

Different iOS devices can have displays of different dimensions and resolutions, but in all devices the display affects the user experience in the same ways:
44 x 44 points is the comfortable minimum size of a tappable UI element.

so as Suraj mentioned in his comment, you can use any size you want as long as they make sense :)

EDIT (i will leave the above answer thou it's not related to the question but it might help someone or clear their understanding related to UIButton Size.

Re: UIButton Spacing

As far as i know, Apple does not have any restriction on spacing, you can use any spacing as long as it makes sense and is not very difficult for the end user to tap a particular UIButton

Re: Placing UIButton in IB

I believe it's just to help the developer place items neatly on the IB. if you follow the default minimum spacing it's good, but not following will not hurt, for sure!

Comment: The question is about spacing, not size

Comment: Oops.. you are right! the answer to the spacing would be somehow similar, as far as i know, Apple does not have any restriction on spacing, you can use any spacing as long as it makes sense and is not very difficult for the end user to tap a particular UIButton.

Comment: Edit your answer to get rid of the downvote. I'll broaden my question to non-apple guidelines too, maybe additional helpful answers will emerge.

Comment: Thanks for editing, you get your points (actually a +2 :-)  I'll leave the question unanswered for now, maybe someone knows some general ux advice too.

Answer (score 4):

The guideline is *at least* 10px.

Good luck!

Comment: Have you got any source for that?

Comment: This is what they taught when I studied UX as part of my degree.
I couldn’t find an official Apple source to show here. However, given you _did_ broaden your question to non-apple guidelines too, here are the [windows guidelines](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2012/04/20/guidelines-for-building-touch-friendly-sites.aspx).